# How do I output several image files from one latex document?

Tags: graphics, tcolorbox

I have code to create several simple cards for a game:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\newcommand{\policy}[2]{ \vspace{1mm}
\tcboxfit[width=2.25in,height=2.8in,title={ {\Large #1 }\vspace{1mm} \\  \large Card Subtype }, colback=white,colframe= black,nobeforeafter]{             {  \raggedright \normalsize #2 }  }} 

\begin{document}
\policy{Name of Card}{Text on the card}
\policy{Name of another Card}{Text on the second card}
\policy{Name of a third Card}{Text on the third card}
\end{document}
```

Now I want each card to be output individually as a png or other image file. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Perhaps this is possible with the `external` library of `tcolorbox`

Comment: You could try to output each card on a separate page and then extract single pages from the pdf file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following code will produce a pdf file with one card on each page and automatically converts each page to one .png independent file.

Instead of article, I've used `standalone` class with `multi` option. This option (`multi=<environment-name>`) allows to crop every page around a certain environment. As `tcboxfit` is a command and not an environment, I've defined an empty environment `foo` and inserted in `policy` definition. This way every `foo` environment is shown in an independent page in pdf result.

As `standalone` allows to apply automatic conversions to pdf results, I've used `Image Magick` to convert the pdf into png. The resulting images are based on .tex name. If we use `cards.tex` the result will be `cards.pdf` but also `cards-0.png`, `cards-1.png`, ...

```
%cards.tex
\documentclass[10pt, multi=foo, border=1mm,
convert={convertexe=convert, density=300, outext=.png}]{standalone}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\newenvironment{foo}{}{}

\newcommand{\policy}[2]{\begin{foo}%
\tcboxfit[width=2.25in,height=2.8in,title={ {\Large #1 }\vspace{1mm} \\  \large Card Subtype }, colback=white,colframe= black,nobeforeafter]{             {  \raggedright \normalsize #2 }  }\end{foo}} 

\begin{document}
\policy{Name of Card}{Text on the card}
\policy{Name of another Card}{Text on the second card}
\policy{Name of a third Card}{Text on the third card}
\end{document}
```

The pdf file will look like

[image]

And cards-0, cards-1 and cards-2.png are:

[image]

[image]

[image]